# "Резиновые" геометрические фигуры на CSS

Tags: css

Доброго времени суток.

Есть прямоугольник с контентом и прямоугольный треугольник через :after для создания прямоугольной трапеции:

```
<div class = "content">Какой-то текст</div>

.content{
    width: 100px;
    height: 444px;
    position:relative;
    background-color:#FFFFFF;
}

.content:after{
    content: '';
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    right: -70px;
    border-top: 444px solid #FFFFFF;
    border-right: 70px solid transparent;
}
```

Получается прямоугольная трапеция 170x444, но она привязана к конкретной высоте.
Вопрос: как растянуть треугольник(.content:after) по высоте блока .content ?

Answer (score 0):

Если я правильно понял Вы хотите чтобы ваш :after растягивался автоматом по высоте всего блока? css врятли так сможет! JS в помощь

```
$(document).ready(function() {  var str = $('.content').height();  $('<style>.content:after{border-top:' + str + 'px solid #000;}</style>').appendTo('head');});
```

[jsfiddle.net](https://jsfiddle.net/genesisplus/62y8r50d/14/)

Comment: Я просто хочу растягиваемую по высоте прямоугольную трапецию :) javascript не вариант. Возможно есть другие способы сделать такую фигуру помимо border?

Comment: Через transform возможно! [jsfiddle.net](https://jsfiddle.net/genesisplus/h7tL8onw/3/)

Comment: но боюсь это тоже не то, можно сделать подругому, создать фигуру svg и тянуть ее исходя из блока, если JS не хотите

Comment: Сделал через transform :) Теперь уголок тянется, спасибо. Трапеция у меня и так состояла из двух частей. Нужно было просто растянуть правильно =) svg, js слишком много чести для одной трапеции ^_^